# Http POST for loading a mock json file

Tags: json, unit-testing, http-post, http-status-code-400, angularjs-1.5

I have an application which hits APIs on the server. But the server isn't developed yet so I am using mock .json files on my local machine to proceed with client side development (which uses angularjs). Some of the APIs need to send POST requests (example: login). When I send POST requests to hit my mock .json files it gives me 400 status error. Is it possible to request .json file with Http Post method ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use POST on local file only GET. One solution is to host your own server and mock from there. There are also website that help you do this for example [Owllang](https://owllang.com)

Comment: Please verify if you can or can't POST request a local file and edit your answer to show greater authority and certainty. Links to relevant documentation may also prove useful in this case.